# syncfusion export pdf show the state of toggle button

Tags: typescript, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion to convert my page into pdf.

I have a toggle button and by default i have set the value to true. So no matter what the state of toggle button is it will always show as on(true) when i export to pdf.

I tried to set the value to local and session storage but that did not help me.

Can you please tell me how to solve this?

Basically if the toggle button is off then pdf should show as off and if it is on and i click on export pdf then it should show on

Answer (score 0):

When converting URL to PDF, we internally load the URL with our HTML converter. It will load the HTML files as it is with initial values of the web page. If you need to update any values in your webpage, then you have to get the HTML string or file with that value for the conversion. Then only it will preserve that values in a HTML to PDF conversion. HTML to PDF converter will preserve the PDF document like how the input HTML file/URL is displayed on a web browser. We could not do any changes in HTML file/URL at the time of conversion. So, kindly provide the filled HTML file/URL to the HTML to PDF conversion.

For your requirement, you have to get the HTML source after completing your operation in the webpage, then you can convert that HTML source text to PDF using HTML string to PDF conversion. Please refer below link for HTML string to PDF conversion,

**UG:** https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/convert-html-to-pdf/webkit#html-string-to-pdf

**Note:** I work for Syncfusion.